# Key Usage, serverAuth, clientAuth and openssl_csr_sign()

Tags: php, ssl, x509, pki, php-openssl

Is it possible with PHP to set key usage when signing requests with `openssl_csr_sign()` using a CA certificate? I cant find any info regarding this.

I really want to differentiate on Client and Server certificates.

Comment: I believe you have to do it with a CONF file. There's another redirection trick, but I don't know how easy it is in PHP. Also see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639). Both use the CONF files to tune a certificate and request.

Comment: *"I really want to differentiate on Client and Server certificates...."* -  Client and Server certificates are just end-entity certificates. I believe there are better ways to signal Client and Server certificates. You probably want to take the topic up on [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/). Its better suited for these types of discussions.